# How to browse code in source tree checked out at particular branch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

How to browse files in `source tree`, while it is checked out at a particular branch or at a commit, without affecting anything in the original repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git worktree` to checkout the content of the other ranch into a **new** folder without affecting the current branch.

## ***`git worktree`***

`git worktree` and it allows you to have multiple instances of the same repository across different folders.

The `wokrtree` create **new folder** with the content of the desired branch but your 3-states will be clean and you will have new 3-states per working folder.

for example:

```
git worktree add <second path>
```

will create another folder on your computer which allow you to work on different branch simultaneously.

---

If you want to remove the worktree use the prune subcommand

> ***`prune`***
>   Prune working tree information in `$GIT_DIR/worktrees`.

Another option to remove it is to delete the `.git/worktrees` folder

[image]

---

If you use rebase later on:

- Note: ([Since Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt))
  you can also use the `git rebase [--no]-autostash` as well.

Comment: thanks a lot very useful answer, are you aware of any git GUI application already using this feature and giving handy feature of browsing full source code into other branches ?

Comment: As for now not yet. buy I assume it will be available soon since its a cool and useful feature once you get to know it

Comment: well after some hunting in various existing applications, found out that gitg provide this functionality in somewhat a limited way as of now. anyways thanks for the help

Comment: GitLens for VSCode started supporting it recently in version 12.